# Why feature vectors have a lot of zero values in Keras VGG16 model's output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract the features from the last layer of VGG16 model in Keras using the following code:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True )


img_path = 'E:\project\KERAS DEEP\poodle.png'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
img_data = image.img_to_array(img)
img_data = np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=0)
img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)
model.summary()
model.layers.pop();
model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
feature = model.predict(img_data)[0]
```

feature variable supposes to be the feature vector but it has a lot of zeros, I think because of relu layer. In Matlab, for example, the extracted features vector seems to have both positive and negative values, how I can get the same with keras model?

The matlab code is:

```
im=imread('poodle.png');
im=imresize(im,[224,224]);
net=vgg16;
trainingFeatures = activations(net, im, 'fc7', ...
'OutputAs', 'rows');
```

the two output vectors `feature` and `trainingFeatures` as following (python output to the left and Matlab's to the right

[image: Samples from the Keras output]
[image]

And here is the tested image:

[image]

Comment: There is no way to answer this if you don't include the equivalent Matlab code and the results you are seeing.

Comment: Edited! I think its more clear now :)

Comment: Which variables are you showing in the two pictures? `feature` and `trainingFeatures`? Also where is ResNet coming into this, it looks like you've only used VGG? Is your python model using ReLu and your MATLAB model using tanh maybe?

Comment: Yes, feature and trainingFeatures. I have edited the code and used vgg16 in both Python and Matlab for more clarification. Keras and Matlab model (vgg16) use the same ReLu layer

Comment: It seems that the Python model discards the negative values, while the Matlab does not!

Comment: The title of your question mentions ResNet50, please be consistent. And I still don't get where you are getting these negative values from, as VGG uses only ReLU activations, so no negative values can be produced, unless your matlab code is outputting the logits and not some particular layer activation.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro due to my understanding, the above codes should extract the features from the same layer, which is the fully connected layer 7. I don't know how to make the Python version extracting the same features with the negative values

Comment: VGG16 has three fully connected layers, there is no fc7. I don't think you are extracting features from the same layers, and that explains any difference.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro there is just a difference in naming, Matlab uses the name fc7 in their documentation while Keras uses fc2 and both refer to the last layer before the classification layer, and both extract 4096 values.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro [Here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/vgg16.html) fc7 extracts the features before ReLU, is that right? If yes, how I can extract the same using Keras model?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be before ReLU, you can't extract the same in Keras as each layer has the ReLU embedded inside the layer. This explains all the differences.

Comment: Thank you! we'll look for more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In my own custom network I have found that zeros generally occur in the same location in the vector regardless of the input image, and that the number of these zero dimensions is related to the dropout keep probability.

So I would infer dropout causes this. Lower dropout keep probability likely causes less zeros, as more non-zero features are needed to ensure important ones make it through the dropout phase.

As for why dropout causes zeros, I’m not sure. It would be interesting to see if the number changes during training.